# Chazzan finishing last phrase of paragraph

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, prayer-book, provenance, loud-quiet

Who decided where to put that indicator in printed siddurim that you see in every paragraph of davening that indicates to the chazzan where to start to read out loud to finish the paragraph, and why did they put the indicator(s) there?

Comment: artscroll.......

Comment: Source........ .?

Comment: It existed before artscroll too

Comment: @DoubleAA: Source........ .?

Comment: @sam, do you really just want to know who made the decision, or do you want to know why it is where it is?

Comment: @SethJ everything you mention,I asked who because if there is a source I would be meayin it.

Comment: @DoubleAA, true, but _sidurim_ have various locations for such marks, so GG *may* be correct to say that each _sidur_'s editor decided where to put them.

Comment: And I have heard chazzans deviate from the marks in the siddur their shul uses.

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/54/759

Comment: @SethJ ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @DoubleAA, for sure. Good find.

Comment: Wow good find,I looked before I posted and nothing.