# Mi-Shebeirach for Shabbat musaf starting point

Tags: minhag, shabbat, tefilla, torah-service, chazzan-prayer-leader

I have noticed in many kehillot, that the sha"tz will begin the Mi-Shebeirach before musaf (Hu y'varech et kol hakahal) at "(U)Mi she-oskim". At first, I thought that this was probably an oversight introduced at some point by a composer, however, I noticed a few weeks ago that sefer haminhagim for Harvard Hillel Orthodox Minyan (where I often daven) says specifically to start at that later point.

On the other hand, the nusach which I have received from my father, who often serves as a ba'al hamusaf and whose father, z"l, was a chazzan, is to begin at the beginning of the tefillah.

If this was a case of the standard practice of ending a tefillah aloud only, it would likely begin "v'yishlach b'rachah", much as the passages of Yekum Purkan are typically ended with the last lines, "maran di vish'maya."

What are the reasons for this machloket?

Comment: He begins there or he begins reciting out loud at that point?

Comment: @Daniel I assume the latter, although seeing as it's said silently, the former may be true.

Comment: I recommend that you ask around at the Harvard Hillel Orthodox Minyan regarding the choices recorded in their book. There is probably a specific reason for each item. In general, though, Chazanim recite only the last part of many prayers aloud, and this could easily be simply an instance of that.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I'm aware of many of the shivolim of davening before the amud, however, seeing as this goes against the nusach I learned from my father, and frankly makes little sense based on the form of the tefillah, I am asking about it in general, giving the specific example as a source for knowing that the practice exists. If it were ending a tefillah aloud only, it would likely begin "v'yishlach b'rachah", much as the passages of Yekum Purkan are typically ended with the last lines, "maran di vish'maya".

Comment: If you're questioning this practice based on a received _nusach_ and the form of the prayer, I recommend you [edit] that info into the question, so you don't get answers like "usually the leader starts aloud partway through, not reciting the whole aloud".

Comment: @msh210 that's exactly the answer I would have given

Comment: @Daniel and I. And, seemingly from his comment, Isaac Moses. I'm closing this as unclear to prevent such answers. It can easily be reopened once clarified.

Comment: I still don't really understand the question. Why is it surprising that not everybody does it exactly the same way as your father?

Comment: @Daniel, the question is why each of the variant approaches, particularly the latter, are used.

Comment: I don't know that this question is really the type of question that we want to entertain. I'll bring it up on meta.

Comment: [posted](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/questions-about-reasons-for-differences-in-davening)

Comment: General case: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-do-we-know-what-the-chazzan-should-say-aloud